# Make Zod parse if available, and if not skip element

Tags: typescript, zod

I've searched through the documentation but find no solution for this case. I've got the following schemas.

```
const RelationSchema = z.object({
    guid: z.string(),
    createdDate: z.preprocess(castToDate, z.date()),
    modifiedDate: z.preprocess(castToDate, z.date()).nullable(),
    name: z.string(),
    publicationtype: z.string(),
    contentType: z.string(),
});
export const NobbRelationsSchema = z.array(NobbRelationSchema);
```

When parsing an array with `NobbRelationsSchema.parse()` I sometimes get back `name` as undefined. In these cases I would like Zod not to throw an error, but instead just remove that element and continue with the rest. A kind of filtering.

The option I see is to use `safeParse` and set `name` as optional and filter out these afterwards. However, it messes up the TypeScript type checking later in code, as `name` should always be set for valid elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The option I see is to use `safeParse` and set name as optional and filter out these afterwards.

I think the simplest thing to do would be to add something special rather than using `z.array`: safe parse an unknown array and filter that. For example:

```js
import { z } from 'zod';
// -- snip your code here --
type NobbRelation = z.TypeOf<typeof RelationSchema>;

function parseData(data: unknown) {
  // First parse the shape of the array separately from the elements.
  const dataArr = z.array(z.unknown()).parse(data);

  // Next parse each element individually and return a sentinal value
  // to filter out. In this case I used `null`.
  return dataArr
    .map(datum => {
      const parsed = RelationSchema.safeParse(datum);
      return parsed.success ? parsed.data : null;
    })
    // If the filter predicate is a type guard, the types will be correct
    .filter((x: NobbRelation | null): x is NobbRelation => x !== null);
}
```

For the most part this shouldn't limit your options. If you have other limitations you want to impose on the `array`, like a maximum length, you can do that when you process the unknown array.

If you have additional post processing you would like to do with `transform`, you could do that with a step after the `filter`.

If you want to have the type for `NobbRelationsSchema` you could derive that as:

```js
type NobbRelations = NobbRelation[]; // Or just write this inline
```